# in-app purchase being restored even before purchase

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, in-app

An update of my existing app has been published on the app store today with in-app purchase to remove ads. I had to put a restore button as it is non-consumable in-app purchase. i have noticed that i can restore the in-app purchase without even purchasing it.

The app went for sale about 4 hours ago. Is this normal for a new app? does the app store take some time to hook up the in-app purchase (probably a silly question)? or have i done something wrong in my code?

Please response if you know whats going on.

EDIT:
Here is the code i used

```
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
{
    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions)
    {
        switch (transaction.transactionState)
        {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                [self completeTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                [self failedTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}


- (void) restoreTransaction: (SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction
{
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]addTransactionObserver:self];    
}


-(void)paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue
{


    if (SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased)
    {
        //save purchase
        NSUserDefaults *savePurchase = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [savePurchase setBool:TRUE forKey:k_Save];
        [savePurchase synchronize];

        _adBanner.hidden = YES;

        // alert after successful restore.
        UIAlertView *restoreTransactionAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Congratulations!"
                                        message:@"Your purchase is restored."
                                        delegate:self
                                        cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                        otherButtonTitles:nil];


        [restoreTransactionAlert show];

    }

    else
    {
        // alert after unsuccessful restore.
        UIAlertView *restoreTransactionAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Restore failed"
                                                message:@"Restore failed. please try again"
                                                delegate:self
                                                cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                otherButtonTitles:nil];

        [restoreTransactionAlert show];

    }

    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];

}


- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError:(NSError *)error
{

}
```

Comment: If this is the first time you have implemented this particular in app purchase, then this is most probably a problem in your code. Please edit the answer with the code which you have used for restoring in app purchases in your app

Comment: thanks for you response akashg. i edited my question with code. could you please help.

Comment: When you tested that the IAP was working did you use a different account? Could it be you can restore it simply because you had purchased it as part of a test? As in the code you've posted, you don't appear to do anything in the Switch statement on a restore?

Comment: when i was testing the IAP i was using test user account, which is different from what i am using now. i had the same issue during the test. but i read somewhere that during sandbox test it always call

-(void)paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue
{
}

instead of

- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError:(NSError *)error
{
}

so i thought it should be ok when it is on the app store.

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation for restoring transactions is incorrect. Your condition in the `-restoreTransactionsCompleted` method, i.e.

```
if (SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased)
```

Will always return true, as SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased is an enum with value 1.

Look up on the documentation on restoring transactions [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Restoring.html).